# CSS for aspect ratio container where height is bigger than width

Tags: css, flexbox, aspect-ratio

I am trying to create a div that keeps its aspect ratio, but where the height is bigger than the width. Most of the questions I search for assume the width is bigger than the height so therefore uses `padding-top` to keep the aspect ratio.

I want a ratio of 9:16 rather than 16:9 which means `padding-top` is more than 100% which means the div becomes taller than the page.

Here is would I would like to achieve when the screen is wide (red is content, grey is the browser window):

[image]

And when the window is narrow:

[image]

Can I achieve this with plain css?

Thanks.

Comment: could you please add css code ?

Answer (score 0):

As @web-tiki already show a way to use `vh`/`vw`, I also need a way to center in the screen, here is a snippet code for **9:16** portrait.

```
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vw * 16 / 9);
  transform: translateY(calc((100vw * 16 / 9 - 100vh) / -2));
}
```

`translateY` will keep this center in the screen. `calc(100vw * 16 / 9)` is expected height for 9/16.`(100vw * 16 / 9 - 100vh)` is overflow height, so, pull up `overflow height/2` will keep it center on screen.

For landscape, and keep **16:9**, you show use

```
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vw * 9 / 16);
  transform: translateY(calc((100vw * 9 / 16 - 100vh) / -2));
}
```

The ratio 9/16 is ease to change, no need to predefined `100:56.25` or `100:75`.If you want to ensure height first, you should switch width and height, e.g. `height:100vh;width: calc(100vh * 9 / 16)` for 9:16 portrait.

If you want to adapted for different screen size, you may also interest

- [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#cover) cover/contain

  - Above style is similar to contain, depends on width:height ratio.
- [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit#)

  - cover/contain for img/video tag
- `@media (orientation: portrait)`/`@media (orientation: landscape)`

  - Media query for `portrait`/`landscape` to change the ratio.